# What is the facebook React Perf.printWasted() instances mean

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In performance tuning my react application, The Perf.printWasted() shows an instance count.

I don't understand why there are 20 instances of Timeline.  I would expect only 1 since that's what I coded, and that's what I see on the webpage and the chrome developer tools.

[image: 20 instances of Timeline]

[image: 1 Timeline react component in developer tools]

[image: 1 Timeline ui widget on the web page]

Comment: There's a bug that doubles the instances count apparently : https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3407 but it does not explain 20 instead of 1.

Comment: saw the double counting is fixed in React 0.13.1

Comment: A bit late to the party, but I came back to this question quiet often. According to https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4911 this refers to the number of times a component has been created.

Comment: still, components seem to be created way too many times. Why might that be?